# Ratio of liquid/glucomannan/xanthan gum for flan or Walden Farms dip

Tags: thickening, custard, consistency, ratio, flan

I'm hoping someone can offer suggestions for what a good ratio of glucomannan and xanthan gum per volume liquid to thicken a flavored liquid(water consistency w/o thickeners) into a result that has a similar consistency either to flan/egg custard or to Walden Farms marshmallow dip, if it's even possible. I'm looking for something that jiggles some but also holds its shape some, and you can scoop spoonfulls of it fairly easily.

3/4 tsp gluc:1/4 tsp xanthan:1 cup liquid gave something that jiggled and held its shape, but was very what I'd call "gummy", and trying to eat it was more like tearing off pieces with the spoon than scooping them; it was pretty elastic. It also formed sort of globs that were kinda separate but kinda attached. I suspect that a better ratio would use less xanthan gum and/or more glucomannan, but I don't really know where to start.

1 tsp gluc:1/32 tsp xanthan:1 cup liquid is good for warm [chocolate] pudding, I've found.

3/4 tsp gluc:no xanthan:1 cup liquid seems to be good for cold puddings that can be poured(don't hold their shape).

If anyone knows what a good starting point for a ratio of these ingredients per amount liquid, I would greatly appreciate the advice.